# CORS Filter not working in spring REST with angularjs client

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, jboss, cors

I created a project witch contains spring rest service that provide json format and angularJS Client witch consume the service and that work perfectly. Now I create an other web project witch contains just the client (angularjs and html views) but I don't know how to access my rest service from this project. I tied  CORS filter for spring REST but it is not working. I can't get data in the the client project (html views).
I still have this error in console :

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/springrestprojet/rest/demande. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

this is what I have done in the client project:

service.js :

```
angular.module('workflowService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Demande', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/rest/demande/:id', {}, {
            'save': {method:'PUT'}
        });
    });
```

application.js :

```
angular.module('todoApp', ['workflowService']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
        when('/demande/list', {templateUrl:'views/demande-list.html', controller:DemandeListController}).
        when('/demande/new', {templateUrl:'views/demande-new.html', controller:DemandeNewController}).
        when('/demande/:id', {templateUrl:'views/demande-detail.html', controller:DemandeDetailController}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/demande/list'}); }]);
```

controller.js

```
function DemandeListController($scope, $location, Demande) {
$scope.demandes = Demande.query();
$scope.gotoDemandeNewPage = function () {
    $location.path("/demande/new");
};
$scope.deleteDemande = function (demande) {
    demande.$delete({'id':demande.idDemande}, function () {
        $location.path('/');
    });
};}
```

and this is what I have done in the rest project :
SimpleCORSFilter.java

```
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) resp;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {} }
```

ClassControleur.java :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/demande", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
   public @ResponseBody List<Demande> list(HttpServletResponse response) {
       connecter();
       List<Demande> ListDemandes = new ArrayList<Demande>();
       ListDemandes = (List<Demande>)rb.getDemandeRepository().findAll() ;

      return ListDemandes  ;
   }
```

web.xml :

```
  <filter>
   <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
   com.springrestprojet.controller.SimpleCORSFilter
   </filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>simpleCORSFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any angular CORS configuration.  Add this to our `.config` and see what happens. Remember to inject `$httpProvider`.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Comment: sorry, can you clarify more ?

Comment: It was just a hunch, but you mentioned CORS.  You need to configure Angular's `$http` service for CORS either on a per request basis, or for all requests using `$httpProvider` in the AngularJS `.config` function.  I'm not saying you haven't already done this, but I can't see it in the code you've provided.

Comment: I add  this : `$resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;

    $resourceProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $resourceProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    delete $resourceProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $resourceProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $resourceProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";`

Comment: but I have this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/springrestprojet/rest/demande. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

Answer (score -1):

finally, I found a solution: I just do a small modification to the URL : 
http://localhost:8080:8080/springprojet/rest/demande/:id.
 now that works fine!