# Applying a curl POST request with $http in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, curl, stripe-payments

I am reading from the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) that I can charge an user with the following curl request:

Definition

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges
```

Request

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u sk_test_PjPAEVD1LXfUuA6XylJPnQX4: \
   -d amount=400 \
   -d currency=eur \
   -d source=tok_16ffrPHW84OuTX9VFTYguruR \
   -d description="Charge for test@example.com"
```

In an Angular setting, I presume that I have to use $http. However, how do you pass on the parameters?

I tried the following

```
$http.post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges', result)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("success", data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("error", data);
            });
```

but received the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: Stripe has a javascript SDK ...use that to make initial token request and pass the response to your server

Comment: I am sorry but nothing of that is clear to me. I have managed to retrieve the token request, but how do I handle the actual charge? That is why I tried to do it this way. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992249/how-to-make-the-actual-stripe-charge-in-angular/32992345#32992345

Comment: Once token is received from stripe you have to send that token to your server so you can create the charge there which you can do with your cURL code. Stripe also has SDK's for server side in most languages also

Comment: Do you have a tutorial on that step? I am not sure what to do

Comment: It's all outlined in their documentation  https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Comment: The error you get may be because you need to "enable" CORS in your angular app.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31006662/108099

Comment: Yes I looked at those forms, but seriously I am not getting it. Where do you send the response to your server? What server? How do integrate it with Angular?

Comment: @glennanthonyb Stripe is a payment gateway. There is no way that OP can set up CORS on their servers. Don't confuse the issue

Comment: ***STEP 3: Sending the form to your server***  Read the documentation thoroughly

Comment: You need to have some code running *server-side* (perhaps using PHP, Ruby, Node.JS, ASP.NET, etc etc etc) that can send the token you generated in the browser/Javascript, and send it to `https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges`. You must not make that call from the front-end (browser) Javascript.

Comment: The short answer is you must have your server make the charge request to stripe

Comment: @charlietfl - I was attempting to address the AngularJS issue with calling API's across origin.  I'm not familliar with Stripes SDK, but based on your original comment I assumed they had a client-side SDK, in which case the client would have no choice but to use CORS (or maybe JSONP), in which case the server must support it.  It is specifically a Node SDK, not a JavaScript SDK - please be clear.

Comment: @glennanthonyb they do have a client side sdk which is the only way to communicate with their servers from client. This has nothing to do with node

Comment: @charlietfl so I could achieve that by transforming the curl request to a http request? on the url: https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges

Comment: From server yes but not from cient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some code running *server-side* (perhaps using PHP, Ruby, Node.JS, ASP.NET, etc etc etc) that takes the token you generated in the browser/Javascript as input, and sends it to `https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges` to make the charge.

You **must not** make that call from the front-end (browser) Javascript/Angular. By doing so, you are **putting your secret key out in public** – your Stripe account would no longer be secure. The only key that should ever feature in your front-end code is the *public key*, which can only be used for making tokens.

Take a look [here](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) for instructions on generating the token and sending it to the server, and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) for instructions on creating the charge server-side.

Comment: Yeah I looked through it, but I still miss the link of having retrieved the token with checkout.js and then passing it to the server? Also, where do I setup the server.

Comment: @JohnAndrews the server you use for your site. Where are you serving your app from now?

Comment: Yeah I get that, but do you have any examples of how to setup that server to be able to accept such server calls?

Comment: @JohnAndrews you haven't answered charlietfl's question. Where are you serving your app from now?

Comment: Just in the cloud (c9.io) with a node.js server

Comment: @charlietfl, it looks like c9.io is a cloud-based IDE. So potentially isn't for hosting a server-side app. JohnAndrews, you need a server to run your code.

Comment: @JohnAndrews perfect, then between the c9.io docs and the Stripe docs (and maybe a beginner's guide to forms in Node.JS) you should have everything you need?

Comment: So the question becomes, how to execute a node.js script in angular?